# Change color single layers OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, layers, color

I want to change the color to a layers after the user has selected the color from the interface

what have I done so far:

```
 var imobile = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource.teren });
   

    $('#color-picker-imobile').on('change', function(){
                        var imobile_color = $('#color-picker-imobile').val();
                        console.log(imobile_color);
                        
                        $.post( "ser_edit_pdf.php", 
                             {
                                  save_setari_imobile: 1,
                                  imobile_color: imobile_color
                             },
                             function( data ) {
                                console.log('save setup');
                                console.log(data);
                                var color = JSON.parse(data);
                                
                                    
                                    //imobile.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({fill: color.color_imobile, opacity: '0,9'}));
                                    imobile.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature){

                                        //console.log(feature.getProperties());
                                        
                                        console.log(color.color_imobile);
                                        
                                          var style = new ol.style.Style({
                                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: color.color_imobile}),
                                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                                  color: [0,0,230], width: 1
                                                })
                                            });
                                            feature.setStyle(style);
                                        });
                                
                                  
                                
                                    
                             });
```

I want to do this without reloading the map with the new setting

I store the layers as follows:

```
var vectorSource = {
                            teren: new ol.source.Vector(),
                            constructii: new ol.source.Vector(),
                            uat: new ol.source.Vector()
                        };
```

I could not find any concrete example for my situation :(

Comment: You can do that with vector layer `.setStyle` method.

Comment: I tried this way: vectorSource.teren.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({fill: color.color_imobile})); return error : Uncaught TypeError: vectorSource.teren.setStyle is not a function

Comment: You do not set style to vector layer source, but to the layer itself. See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html

Comment: I added to the layer the style: imobile.setStyle (new ol.style.Style ({fill: color.color_imobile})); now it's not a mistake just that the color doesn't change automatically on the map :(

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant part of the code that does not work for you.

Comment: imobile.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({fill: color.color_imobile, opacity: '0,9'})); no refresh maps by the new color selected

Comment: The layer vector store in the imobile variable :   var imobile = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource.teren });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116807/discussion-between-codercoder42-and-tomazicm).

Comment: I managed to thank him nicely !!